# SQL Query to read a certain number of records with nested data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view with this structure:

```
EntryId | EntryName | ParentEntryId | Depth | DatePosted
```

What I want to do is to write an SQL query that will bring the first 2 entries with Depth=0 along with the first descendants (based on the ParentEntryId). Below, I provided an example output.

```
EntryId | EntryName | ParentEntryId | Depth | DatePosted | ChildCount
1       | a         | NULL          | 0     | 1/12/2012  | 2
4       | b         | 1             | 1     | 1/14/2012  | 5
13      | c         | 1             | 1     | 1/15/2012  | 3
3       | d         | NULL          | 0     | 1/11/2012  | 1
12      | e         | 3             | 1     | 1/14/2012  | 0
```

I know I can bring the entries with depth = 0 easily like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 FROM Entries WHERE Depth=0 ORDER BY DatePosted DESC
```

However, I am not sure how to bring the associated sub-entries. For example for the main entry with Id=1, I want to bring the entries (first descendants) whose ParentEntryId = 1. I also need to bring the count of the child entries of these first descendants. Any ideas?

Comment: By subentry you mean all children of that entry or just next descendant?

Comment: @DhruvJoshi just the descendant and the count of the subentries of the descendant

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange I understand and agree. But sometimes we can be in a rush and try to explain quickly to get an assistance soon. I just did not know how to achieve what I asked for.

Comment: And unless you provide details nobody can really help. The reason people ask questions is because they don't know how to achieve the desired results. However when a question is asked without enough details people can't answer it because they don't understand the question. This is clearly the case here. Two people have taken wild shots in the dark and no idea if it is even close.

Comment: @SeanLange I wonder if my question is more clear with the additional information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this with a recursive cte..  You should make sure the performance meets your standards though if you're using this on a large record set

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  [EntryId],
            [EntryName],
            [ParentEntryId],
            [Depth],
            [DatePosted],
            [EntryId] [Root],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DatePosted DESC) [Rn],
            CAST(EntryId AS VARCHAR(MAX)) [Path]
    FROM    Entries
    WHERE   [Depth] = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  e.[EntryId],
            e.[EntryName],
            e.[ParentEntryId],
            e.[Depth],
            e.[DatePosted],
            [Root],
            Rn,
            [Path] + ',' + CAST(e.EntryId AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM    Entries e
            JOIN cte ON cte.EntryID = e.ParentEntryId 
)
SELECT  [EntryId],
        [EntryName],
        [ParentEntryId],
        [Depth],
        [DatePosted],
        ChildCount
FROM    cte c1
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT (*) - 1 AS ChildCount 
                     FROM cte c2 
                     WHERE c2.[Path] LIKE c1.[Path] + '%'
                    ) oa
WHERE   Rn <= 2  -- only gets the first 2 records with depth = 0
        AND Depth <= 1  -- limit to only top level child records
ORDER BY [Root],
        [ParentEntryID]
```

Comment: This would give the ChildCount as the _total_ number of descendants, not the number of _first_ descendants. I understood the OP's question as wanting just the number of children, not grandchildren and further descendants etc. but the question isn't fully clear.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the UNION ALL returns duplicate entries.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your updated question, below query will yield perfect results

```
SELECT 
   EntryId , EntryName , ParentEntryId , Depth , DatePosted, ChildCount 
  FROM 
    (   
      SELECT 
        TOP 10 
          E1.EntryId , E1.EntryName , E1.ParentEntryId , E1.Depth , E1.DatePosted, 
           (
             SELECT 
               COUNT(1) 
             FROM Entries E2 
              WHERE E2.ParentEntryID =E1.EntryID
             ) as ChildCount 
      FROM Entries E1 
       WHERE E1.Depth=0

      UNION 

      SELECT 
        E1.EntryId , E1.EntryName , E1.ParentEntryId , E1.Depth , E1.DatePosted, 
        (
            SELECT 
            COUNT(1) 
            FROM Entries E3 
            WHERE E3.ParentEntryID =E1.EntryID
            ) as ChildCount 
       FROM Entries E1 
        LEFT JOIN Entries E2 ON E1.ParentEntryID= E2.EntryID AND E2.Depth=0
    )
    ORDER BY ParentEntryID , Depth ASC, DatePosted
```

Comment: this makes sense, I will try and keep you posted, thanks!

Comment: I think that the query after `UNION` needs to be somehow connected with the query before `UNION`. Otherwise, it will return some records independent from the main entries (depth = 0).

Answer (score 1):

Without having any input data it's difficult to give you an accurate answer. However, I think something like this is what you're looking for.

I used a simple data set to test. I've tried to group the layout of the script so you can easily see the number of children based on the ParentEntryID:

```
-- Create a table.
DROP TABLE Entries
CREATE TABLE Entries
(
    EntryID         INT,
    EntryName       VARCHAR(20),
    ParentEntryID   INT,
    Depth           INT, 
    DatePosted      DATE     
);

-- Populate the table
INSERT INTO Entries VALUES 
 (1,  'A', null, null, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
,(73, 'C', 1, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

,(16, 'B', 73, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
,(85, 'G', 73, 1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
,(74, 'D', 73, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

,(75, 'E', 74, 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
,(76, 'F', 74, 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

,(86, 'H', 85, 3, DATEADD(DAY, 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
,(87, 'I', 85, 3, DATEADD(DAY, 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))

,(88, 'J', 86, 4, DATEADD(DAY, 3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))

,(89, 'K', 88, 5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
,(90, 'L', 88, 5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
,(91, 'M', 88, 5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
,(92, 'N', 88, 5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Then you can use a recursive common table expression. I have commented out `TOP 2` and `WHERE Depth = 0` to give more results. (I think this makes it easier to understand based on the small amount of test data.) You can substitute those out for your requirements.

```
;WITH MyEntries (EntryID, ParentEntryID, EntryName, Depth, DatePosted)
AS
(
    -- Anchor 
    SELECT  EntryID, ParentEntryID, EntryName, Depth, DatePosted 
    FROM    Entries
    --WHERE   Depth = 0
    UNION ALL
    -- Recursive
    SELECT  Recurs.EntryID, Recurs.ParentEntryID, Recurs.EntryName, Recurs.Depth, Recurs.DatePosted
    FROM    Entries AS Recurs     
            INNER JOIN MyEntries AS Anchor
                ON Recurs.EntryID = Anchor.ParentEntryID    
    --WHERE Recurs.Depth = 0    
)
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        --TOP 2                 
        ME.EntryID
        ,ME.ParentEntryID
        ,ME.EntryName
        ,ME.Depth
        ,ME.DatePosted
        ,COALESCE(VT.ChildCOunt, 0) AS 'ChildCount'
FROM    MyEntries AS ME
LEFT JOIN   (SELECT  ParentEntryID, COUNT(1) AS 'ChildCount'
            FROM Entries
            GROUP BY ParentEntryID ) AS VT
        ON ME.EntryID = VT.ParentEntryID            
ORDER BY        
        ME.DatePosted;
```

I'm not sure this is the most efficient way, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have top 10 but no order by so your logic is flawed from the start. You also don't have any columns listed. As a pure guess since you didn't provide much detail I am thinking something like this.

```
select [Columns]
from Entries
where ParentEntryID in 
(
    select top 10 EntryID
    from Entries
    where Depth = 10
    order by SomeColumn
)
```

Or perhaps you need a recursive cte to get the whole tree under each one?